# Range of state space for MuJoco HalfCheetah

Tags: python, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I have been trying to identify the range of each feature in MuJoCo's Half Cheetah environment. The only relevant piece of information I can find is [the xml file](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/mujoco/assets/half_cheetah.xml). Does anyone know where can I locate the max and min of each feature in the state feature vector?

Answer (score 1):

The `observation_space` is set in this [file](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/mujoco/mujoco_env.py) when this [line](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/220ae8487d9436fba0322b18bcb0402790c25335/gym/envs/mujoco/half_cheetah.py#L7) is called (for HalfCheetah env)

To check the `observation_space` of any environment:

```
import gym
env = gym.make('CartPole-v0') # change the env name here
print('Max of observation_space:',env.observation_space.high)
print('Min of observation_space:',env.observation_space.low)
```

Output:

```
Max of observation_space: [4.8000002e+00 3.4028235e+38 4.1887903e-01 3.4028235e+38]
Min of observation_space: [-4.8000002e+00 -3.4028235e+38 -4.1887903e-01 -3.4028235e+38]
```

Comment: The observation space is different from state space. For instance, in mujoco humanoid, the dimension of state space is 17. However, the dimension of the observation space reaches 376.